# Construction of a peculiar series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Construct a sequence $z_n \in \mathbb C$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{n} \frac{1}{|z_n|^2}$ diverges and $\forall (i,j)$ with $i\neq j$, $|z_i-z_j|\geq 1$.

What make this problem tough is that one needs a sequence such that $z_n$ does not go too fast to infinity, but at the same time such that the $z_n$ are sufficiently far apart from one another.

I did not succeed in building such a sequence, but it is clear that the $z_n$ cannot be all real numbers.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: How many points with mutual distance $\geqslant 1$ can you place on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = R$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sum_{(m,n) \ne (0,0)} \frac{1}{|m+i\,n\,|^2} =\ ?$$